# Javascript how to update count?

Tags: javascript

I've only been learning javascript for about 2 weeks now, I did an example in my book but I wanted to integrate what I've learned so far. Unfortunately, I haven't had any success. I have given on up trying it myself so here I am. I need help.

I want to show the count on the the id="counter", both added items and deleted items. I'm having a hard time updating the count when I delete the items.

HTML:

```
 <div id="page1">
    <h1>Listking logo</h1>
    <h2>buy groceries<span id="counter"></span></h2>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>Fresh figs</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="button">
        <a href="/additem" id="add">add list item</a>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <a href="/deleteItem" id="remove">remove list item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var elList, addLink, removeLink, newEl, newText, counter, listItems;
elList = document.getElementById('list');
addLink = document.getElementById('add');
counter = document.getElementById('counter');
removeLink = document.getElementById('remove');

//creates list Item when the link:add list item is clicked.
function addItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    newEl = document.createElement('li');
    newText = document.createTextNode('New list item');
    newEl.appendChild(newText);
    elList.appendChild(newEl);
}
//deletes items from the list
function deleteItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    item = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
    elList.removeChild(item);


}
//updates the count on id="counter"
function updateCount(){
    listItems = elList.getElementsByTagName('li');
    counter.innerHTML = listItems.length;

}

removeLink.addEventListener('click', deleteItem, false);
addLink.addEventListener('click', addItem, false);
elList.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', updateCount, false);
elList.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', updateCount, false);
```

Comment: It's working for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/33x9nm12/. What problem are you having?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. The code will delay a bit the execution for the `'node deletion'` to finish before doing the count:

```
function updateCount(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        listItems = elList.getElementsByTagName('li');
        counter.innerHTML = listItems.length;
    }, 100);
}
```

You can event put a delay of `1` instead of `100` and it will work.

Another alternative is to don't register `DOMNodeInserted` ad `DOMNodeRemoved` listeners and instead add `updateCount()` call at the end of `addItem()` and `deleteItem()` functions

**EDIT:**

Here are working JSfiddle samples for both solutions:

- [Adding delay with setTimeout](http://jsfiddle.net/leofcx/so97t1or/)
- [Removing listeners](http://jsfiddle.net/leofcx/so97t1or/1/)

Comment: Solved the problem! Although, I haven't read about  delay. This has been very informative. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//elList.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', updateCount, false);
//elList.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', updateCount, false);
elList.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', updateCount, false);
```

just register DOMSubtreeModified

Comment: This also solved the problem! thank you! These codes will definitely go into my notes!